# html canvas to maintain aspect ratio and be as large as it can be inside a parent element? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, canvas

I'm trying to scale a canvas to a specific aspect ratio that takes up as much room as is available in the parent container. Here's the CSS and HTML:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
  background-color: white;
  gap: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

#canvas1 {
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
  object-fit: fit;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*
  what to set width and height to??
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h1>header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h1>footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use `object-fit` to have the canvas take up the entire available space while maintaining the aspect ratio, but it doesn't. Setting `width` or `height` to 100% seems to ignore the `aspect-ratio`. I'm trying to keep the entire thing on the screen as the window resizes, which is why I'm expanding the grid to take up the entire space, but the canvas is not scaling up or down as I'd like it to.

I've tried all kinds of things but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/csells/53bgLw1z/25/

Comment: You'll have to use JS to draw on that canvas anyway, any reason you don't use it to also set the canvas size appropriately? It's certainly better if you buffer size matches the display size.

Answer (score 1):

Setting

```
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
```

does work for me and it also keeps the aspect ratio.

Comment: That does work *except* it doesn't keep the grid inside the window. Instead, as the width gets larger, the height matches and scrolls the grid outside the browser window. Is there a way to solve this problem that keeps the width and height as large as they can be *without* causing the grid to scroll while also keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: @csells Since you are using a canvas therefore use js, you could use javascript to automatically resize the canvas by setting canvas.width and canvas.height to the width of theParentDiv.clientWidth or .clientHeight

Comment: I'd love to see a working example of that; I haven't been able to make it work.